# Django how to send_mail via local sendmail

Tags: django, sendmail

I would like to send out email via local sendmail.
my email settings in settings.py is below

```
EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'default_from_email@email.com'
```

the error is [Errno 61] Connection refused

Comment: Is there an smtp server running on your localhost?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes. the rails app in the same server works perfectly fine.

Comment: If the connection is refused, the Rails app using the **same** settings can't be working perfectly fine. Can you `telnet localhost 25`?

Comment: Rails have the default sendmail config which I use. my telnet result is `220 domain_name ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2; Tue, 22 Dec 2020 10:51:52`